# Вывод битмапа в окно

Tags: windows, c++, visual-studio

Дайте, пожалуйста, код функции, которая выводит в окно картинку из буфера

```
unsigned char* pDispBuffer;
```

Answer (score 3):

Это можно по разному делать, в зависимости от того, что и где выводится. Например, для Direct2D с помощью DrawBitmap: [How to Draw a Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756684(v=vs.85).aspx). Голым Windows API так (hBitmap - это то, что вы собираетесь выводить):

```
PAINTSTRUCT     paintstruct;
BITMAP          bitmap;

HDC hdc = BeginPaint(handle, &paintstruct);
HDC hdcMemory = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HGDIOBJ oldBitmap = SelectObject(hdcMemory, hBitmap);

GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bitmap), &bitmap);
BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, hdcMemory, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
SelectObject(hdcMemory, oldBitmap);

DeleteDC(hdcMemory);
EndPaint(handle, &paintstruct);
```

Comment: Так то оно так, но у меня не hBitmap, а unsigned char* . Администратор почему то мой вопрос переиначил в BITMAP.
Применяю функцию CreateDIBSection, но увы все пикселы нули.

Comment: @Antaun, здесь телепатов нет, укажите в вопросе неработающий кусок кода.